# How to rig an IK leg with 2 knee joints (Animal Leg Rigging)

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm trying to rig a leg with two joints and have been struggling for ages trying to add IK. The chain is 4 bones long so forms 2 knees (Fig 1).

Ideally I can imagine having 2 pole targets (Fig 2) but I don't see that the IK solver allows that.

The kind of poses that are difficult to achieve are having the knee joints pointing in different directions. This can be achieved by rotating the bone between the joints but it is awkward to animate and you lose the connection to the pole target (Fig 3)

Does anyone have any ideas how to rig this effectively?

Thanks!

**Fig 1**

[image: rig schematic]

**Fig 2**

[image: rig schematic with pole targets]

**Fig 3 (top view)**

[image: top view of awkward poses]

Comment: I don't know if that's the best idea but have you tried to create another IK on another of your bones, therefore a second controller and a second pole target? It would mean that your first chain would be shorter. Also, you talk about a current chain of 4, shouldn't it be 3?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @moonboots. I've tried adding a second IK to bone c using bone b as the target. As you say, I needed to shorten the first chain to clear the dependency cycle but that then means you can't use bone a to influence the whole leg.

Comment: @moonboots, yes, I should probably have described it as length 3. I included bone a, which I use as the IK target, as part of the chain but it isn't actually parented to bone b.

Comment: if you assign a IK to the bone D, with a controller on its bottom, perhaps with no pole target, but just a target controller, and assign a Child Of to this controller with the first controller as the Target (click on Set Inverse)? Also note that you can limit the IK bones rotations in Properties > Bone > Inverse Kinematics, so it doesn't go crazy.

Comment: You may also find it helpful to constrain the knees to only rotate on one axis. You can set this in the Inverse Kinematics section under the bone data tab in the settings window.

Comment: @moonboots Fantastic, works well, thanks! Was there a specific reason you suggested a 'child of' constraint on the joint 2 controller? Did you want to post as an answer I can accept or should I write up an answer?

Comment: I also experimented with using a damped track or track to constraint on bone D, rather than an IK. The damped track seems to give identical result, whereas the track to leads to slight differences.

Comment: The Child Of makes your second controller follow the move of your first, so that you don't always have to move the second one, I don't know if it's useful to you though. I'm going to test the Damped Track you're talking about. I tested the Track To but I was not sure about it.

Comment: oh yes it looks like Damped Track works better than the Track To, I'm going to add it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @moonboots. Sorry, I should have clarified: was there a reason you suggested 'child of' rather than just parenting with offset? Was it just to make it switchable?

Comment: you're right, no reason   ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, here is the solution we've found:

- Create a controller for your foot, deparent it, parent the foot to this controller.
- Choose this controller as the *Target* of your calf's *IK*.
- The *Chain Length* of your calf's *IK* constraint must be 2.
- Create a new controller at the bottom of your bone D.
- Parent this second controller to the foot controller (Keep Offset).
- Parent the pole target of your calf to the foot controller (Keep Offset).
- Add a *Copy Location* constraint to your foot so that it sticks to the calf.
- Add a *Damped Track* or an *IK* constraint to the bone D and choose the new controller as your Target

Also note that you can limit the IK bones rotations in *Properties* > *Bone* > *Inverse Kinematics*, or with a *Limit Rotation* constraint, depending on the bones and the chosen solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rig it like a normal leg. There are no 2 knee joints. There is only 1 knee and heel. Almost every animal walks on it's fingers.

Provide a control for the heel like on every human rig - up/down lift and left/right pivot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There are examples where this isn't the case, such as frogs which are plantigrade so don't walk on their toes but have an arrangement as in the original question. This could also apply to hypothetical creatures or objects. I think the accepted answer handles these cases better and functions as I had in mind.